# Macbook Air Fan running frequently and loudly

Tags: macbook-pro

Not sure if there is something running that is causing it. Here is my activity monitor.
[image]

[image]

Just wondering if there is something going on here that shouldn't. Otherwise I'll just go ahead and reset the SMC

Comment: In Activity Monitor, type Google Chrome into the Search field in the upper right. If you have many Google Chrome Helper processes running, that may be a culprit. *Do the fans stop when Chrome is not running?* Numerous Helper processes can be traced back to extensions and plugins.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest explanation is that the MacBook Air is by no means a performance Mac. Their processors range from 1.1 GHz to around 1.8GHz. Some have 8 GB of RAM, while others have just 4 GB, and some (like one of my family member's MacBook Air) have only 2 GB. Graphics processing units and other parts follow suit. In short, the MacBook Air sacrifices performance for portability, which isn't necessarily a bad thing, but it does mean that if you try to do a lot on it or preform hardware-intensive tasks on it, it will get pretty warm and the fans will go pretty high.